# Django Formset Custom Field Exclusion

Tags: django, python-3.x

I created a form that has 2 radio buttons (Male/Female).  Below it will have an input box for First Name and Last Name.  If I use formset to replicate the form, it will include the radio buttons for every input box and I wanted to exclude that.  Assume that once a user select "Male" the names should matches their gender selection.

The output should look like so:

O Male     O Female

First Name: _______________   Last Name: _______________

First Name: _______________   Last Name: _______________

...

```
forms.py

from django import forms


class NameForm (forms.Form):
    GENDER = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female')
    )

    gender = forms.ChoiceField (widget = forms.RadioSelect, choices = GENDER)
    first_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20)
    last_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20)


Shell Output:
>>> from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
>>> from nameform.forms import NameForm
>>> 
>>> NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, extra = 2)
>>> formset = NameFormSet ()
>>> for form in formset:
...     print (form.as_table())
... 
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-gender_0">Gender:</label></th><td><ul id="id_form-0-gender">
<li><label for="id_form-0-gender_0"><input id="id_form-0-gender_0" name="form-0-gender" type="radio" value="Male" /> Male</label></li>
<li><label for="id_form-0-gender_1"><input id="id_form-0-gender_1" name="form-0-gender" type="radio" value="Female" /> Female</label></li>
</ul></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-first_name">First name:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-first_name" maxlength="20" name="form-0-first_name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-last_name">Last name:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-last_name" maxlength="20" name="form-0-last_name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-gender_0">Gender:</label></th><td><ul id="id_form-1-gender">
<li><label for="id_form-1-gender_0"><input id="id_form-1-gender_0" name="form-1-gender" type="radio" value="Male" /> Male</label></li>
<li><label for="id_form-1-gender_1"><input id="id_form-1-gender_1" name="form-1-gender" type="radio" value="Female" /> Female</label></li>
</ul></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-first_name">First name:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-1-first_name" maxlength="20" name="form-1-first_name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-last_name">Last name:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-1-last_name" maxlength="20" name="form-1-last_name" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a form and formset. The form containing just the names, the formset containing the repeating elements.

It doesn't really make sense to use a repeating form class, then hack it to treat the first one differently.

Alternatively if this is a data problem (say legacy interface), and the form needs to contain both.. then you could potentially hide all other elements and use javascript to fill in the hidden gender selections.

Really though, you should be using a `Form` and `FormSet`.

```
{{ form.as_p }}
{% for form in formset %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```